# JQuery site navigation

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, navigation

I'm attempting to perform the most basic navigation with JQuery and I'm failing miserably.

I have multiple .html files with various content, but I want to have a persistent page and load content into a div.  The way I have navigation implemented at the moment:

1. User clicks NavLink1
2. JQuery executes the following:

> event.preventDefault()
>   (#my-content-div).load(NavLink1-content);
>
> URL now displays as "www.mydomain.com/#NavLink1".
>
> How in the world can I implement direct linking to #NavLink1, and/or implement a system whereas a user browses to www.mydomain.com/NavLink1 and the content loads properly?

My navigation code for one nav link:

```
    $("#story-button-link").click(function(event){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("#landing-page-article").load('./story.html', function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: What you are looking for is server side url rewriting - *easy* in Apache, crapshoot in IIS.

Comment: I have access to .htaccess, so is this the approach I should take?  Right now it contains only my futile attempt at CORS (I think my host is shite and doesn't REALLY support it).

Comment: This is the only approach to take. Anything else would be hacky and non xbrowser friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind supporting only newer browser versions, you could use HTML5 history management features - [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to be specific, which allows you to change the URL to `yourdomain.com/NavLink1` while not reloading the page, allowing you to do the same thing but keeping the URLs intact.

If you **do** mind older browsers, you could use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) which solves cross-browser compatibility problems. On newer browsers it will use the HTML5 features, and on older versions it will revert to hash changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm expecting older browsers.  This happens to be a wedding website with RSVP included, so I should probably support IE.

Comment: @Chad_C: My solution *does* support IE - the part about History.js. If this answer was helpful to you, please accept it as the correct answer so this question can be marked as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists -- History.js is included and I've followed the confusing documentation.  I've even tried removing the hashbang and using regular links such as /home, /navlink1, etc., and they simply return a 404.  I'm still trying to research the proper solution that will also support refreshes.

Comment: I'm using the .click() event to handle all navigation, so maybe that's my problem.  Edited my post to include nav code.